# Can the untyped lambda calculus be implemented using generics only?

Tags: generics, rust, traits, lambda-calculus

Consider the following implementation of the untyped lambda calculus:

```
pub enum Term {
    Var(usize), // a variable with a De Bruijn index
    Abs(Box<Term>), // an abstraction
    App(Box<Term>, Box<Term>) // an application
}

impl Term {
    ...
}
```

I feel that this design, while simple and concise, could benefit from being translated to traits. Different terms should have different sets of methods, e.g. only abstractions should be "unabstractable" and only applications should be evaluable.

I'm aware of the usual arguments in the enums vs. traits; even if enums is the better choice here I'd still want to know if it's possible.

My basic building blocks so far are more or less as follows:

```
#[derive(Clone, PartialEq, Eq)]
pub struct Var(usize);

#[derive(Clone, PartialEq, Eq)]
pub struct Abs<T: Term>(T);

#[derive(Clone, PartialEq, Eq)]
pub struct App<T: Term, U: Term>(T, U);

pub trait Term: Clone {
    fn abs(self) -> Abs<Self> { Abs(self) }

    fn app<T: Term>(self, other: T) -> App<Self, T> { App(self, other) }

    fn update_free_variables(&mut self, added_depth: usize, own_depth: usize);

    fn _apply<T: Term>(&mut self, other: &mut T, depth: usize); // this is a helper function that enables term tree traversal for Abs<T>::apply

    fn is_reducible(&self, limit: usize, count: &usize) -> bool;

    fn beta_reduce(&mut self, order: Order, limit: usize, verbose: bool) -> usize;
}

impl Var {
    pub fn new(index: usize) -> Self {
        assert!(index > 0);
        Var(index)
    }
}

impl<T: Term> Abs<T> {
    fn unabs(self) -> T {
        self.0
    }

    fn apply<U: Term>(mut self, other: &mut U) -> T {
        self._apply(other, 0);
        self.unabs()
    }
}

impl<T: Term, U: Term> App<T, U> {
    fn unapp(self) -> (T, U) {
        (self.0, self.1)
    }
}

// and some impl Term for X
```

While it's pretty easy to implement the basic functionalities, there are a few spots where I'm struggling to come up with the right solution. I need to be able to do the following:

- create a parser able to interpret any term, from plain variables to complex terms, with a single function
- substitute any variable (no matter how deeply nested) with another variable *or a different term*
- recursively reduce terms (I'm not sure if that would be possible with a parsed term that would probably have to be a trait object)

I'd prefer to attempt to implement it on my own, I just need some advice regarding the direction. Is it even possible without an enum wrapper? If so, what approach should I take (in terms of object safety, `unsafe` trickery etc.)?

Comment: I'm aware that at this point the code isn't object safe, but I'm not sure if making it so will help my case (and there's plenty of code I'd need to adjust). It's just a reference showing the general idea.

Answer (score 2):

#### Enums vs. traits

> Different terms should have different sets of methods, e.g. only abstractions should be "unabstractable" and only applications should be evaluable.

I do not think that this is a good argument for the trait-based design. Through pattern matching, enums expose the differences between the types of terms at runtime, but traits hide these differences, forcing you to treat all terms the same way. You will probably not know the types of your terms at compile time, so it doesn't make much sense to give different types of terms different methods. If you want to use functionality specific to each type of term rather than solely interacting with terms polymorphically through a uniform interface, then you should use an enum-based design.

If you decide to stick with the trait-based implementation, you will need to remove all of the generic methods and use trait objects instead. You will not be able to use dynamic dispatch with `Term` if it has generic methods, because it will not be object safe.

One potential advantage of the trait-based design is extensibility, but in this situation it is not a concern, as the definition of the untyped lambda calculus is fixed.

#### The three problems

> create a parser able to interpret any term, from plain variables to complex terms, with a single function

It should be reasonably simple to parse expressions if all applications are required to be surrounded by parentheses. I don't have much experience with parsing, but I would probably try a recursive approach like this:

```
To read one term, given a mutable reference to a variable stack (which begins empty):
    If the next character is an opening parenthesis:
        Consume it.
        Read a term.
        Read a term.
        Make sure the next character is a closing parenthesis, and consume it.
        Return an application of the two terms.
    If the next character is a lambda:
        Consume it.
        Make sure the next character is a variable, then consume it.
        Make sure the next character is a dot, and consume it.
        Push the variable to the variable stack.
        Read a term.
        Pop the variable off of the stack.
        Return an abstraction of the term.
    If the next character is a variable:
        Consume it.
        Search the variable stack find the first index of the variable from the top.
        Return a variable term with this index.
```

You could modify this to accept common shortcuts in lambda calculus notation, such as `(a b c)` for `((a b) c)`. Currently, it would accept `λx.λy.λz.((x z) (y z))` but not `λx.λy.λz.x z (y z)`.

> substitute any variable (no matter how deeply nested) with another variable or a different term

I assume that the number stored by a variable term is the number of abstraction layers between the point where the variable is introduced and the point where it is used. If this is the case, then you can traverse the structure recursively, while remembering the current abstraction depth. When a variable is encountered that matches the number, it is replaced with the given term, except that all of the free variables in the term, which can be found by looking for variables with a number greater than their abstraction depth in the given term, should have the current abstraction depth added to their number to account for the difference in levels. When an application is encountered, the substitution process is recursively performed in both of its children. When a new abstraction is encountered, the substitution is performed recursively in its body, with the abstraction depth increased by 1 to account for the new layer.

If you really want to use traits, then `Term` would have a method like this:

```
fn substitute(&mut self, variable_number: usize, other: &Term);
```

Just to clarify the numbering system, is the following correct?

`λn.λf.λx.(f ((n f) x))` → `Abs(Abs(Abs(App(Var(1),App(App(Var(2),Var(1)),Var(0))))))`

> recursively reduce terms (I'm not sure if that would be possible with a parsed term that would probably have to be a trait object)

Although cumbersome, this is possible with trait objects. You could define two methods in `Term`, the first of which will do nothing except in the `Abs` implementation, where it takes a term and returns the body of the abstraction, substituting the given term at variable index 0. The second method will do nothing except in the `App` implementation, where it will call the first method on the left term of the application, passing the right term. Using a similar strategy, you can define methods to find beta-reducible terms, and by combining these methods you have a messy emulation of enum pattern matching, which would be a much better tool for this task.

You may find [this paper](http://www.lsv.fr/Publis/PAPERS/PDF/sinot-jlc05.pdf) helpful when implementing beta-reduction. I did not read much of it, but it appears to provide strategies for efficient beta-reduction algorithms.

#### Enums vs. traits again

Although the same behavior can be achieved with enums and traits, enums are a better choice when extensibility is not required and it is necessary to analyze and rearrange the structure of the data in intricate ways. For this problem, an enum-based solution is probably superior.

Comment: I updated my question - I'll be happy to polish it further if anything is still unclear (like I overcomplicated beta-reduction by referring to just one of its building blocks). Regarding the numbering system you are correct - I should have mentioned that I'm using De Bruijn indices (I think they are the simplest way to go implementation-wise).

Comment: I have converted most of the basic code to trait objects, but I have come across an obstacle: the `substitute` function where I'm using `mem::swap` complains that `Term does not have a constant size known at compile-time`. I could make it possible by declaring that `trait Term: Sized`, but this would destroy object safety. Is there any way around this?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to use `mem::swap` on `Term` trait objects because different types of terms have different representations in memory. For what purpose are you trying to use it?

Comment: That's right - the problem is I don't know how to go around it; I wanted to perform substitution on a variable.